# Fallo de Boostrap en Google Chrome

Tags: php, html5, bootstrap, aplicación-web, responsive

Estoy realizando una aplicación Web, pero en Google Chrome el diseño no se ve 100% responsivo; en firefox si. ¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Estoy utilizado html, php y boostrap (BootstrapCDN)

Imagen de Google Chrome

[image: Imagen de Google Chrome]

Imagen de Firefox
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos para estos casos es mejor agregar tu codigo que estas aplicando para poder darte una mejor respuesta , edita tu pregunta =>[edit] <= y agrega el codigo respectivo

Comment: ¿has puesto la meta viewport? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colocando `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">` se solucionó el problema.

Comment: Hola Taylor, considera aceptar la solución que te dió Montaycabe, si no sabes cómo hacerlo puedes revisar: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)